# I can't set value in my dev extreme select box with javascript. It empties when full. But it doesn't select correct value when empty

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, devextreme

Enum EStokGrup

```
public enum EStokGrup
    {
        Meyve = 1,
        Sebze = 2,
        Diger=3
    }
```

Controller.cs

```
public JsonResult GetStokGruplar()
        {
            var stokGruplar = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EStokGrup)).Cast<EStokGrup>()
                            .Select(e => new SelectListItem()
                            {
                                Text = e.ToString(),
                                Value = ((int)e).ToString()
                            }).ToList();

            DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions = new DataSourceLoadOptions();
            var loadResult = DataSourceLoader.Load(stokGruplar, loadOptions);
            return Json(loadResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <div class="form-group">               
                    @(Html.DevExtreme().SelectBox().ID("Grup").Name("Grup")
                    .DataSource(d => d.Mvc().LoadAction("GetStokGruplar").Key("Value"))
                    .DisplayExpr("Text")
                    .ValueExpr("Value")
                    .Placeholder("Stok Grup Seçiniz")
                    )
                </div>
            </div>
```

Js Code Same page

```
function OnSelectionChanged(selectedItems) {
        var data = selectedItems.selectedRowsData[0];
        $('#ID').val(data.ID);
        $("#StokKod").dxTextBox("instance").option("value", data.StokKod);
        $("#StokAd").dxTextBox("instance").option("value", data.StokAd);
        $("#Ambalaj").dxTextBox("instance").option("value", data.Ambalaj);        
        $("#Birim").dxSelectBox("instance").option("value", "Kg");        
        $("#Grup").dxSelectBox("instance").option("value", data.Grup);    
        $("#Aktif").dxCheckBox("instance").option("value", data.Aktif);    
        $("#btnEkleKaydet").dxButton("instance").option("text", "Kaydet");
        $("#btnYeni").dxButton("instance").option("visible", "false");
        $("#StokKod").dxTextBox("instance").focus();  
    }
```

When I select the row from the grid, other data comes, but the selectbox data does not.I give screenshots as an example.Also, if I select from the datagrid with the value selected in the select box, the select box is empty.When I print the console as Console.log(data.Group) the correct data is written to the console. But it does not select via the select box.Thanks for helps friends

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().SelectBoxFor(m => m.StokBirimler).ID("Birim").Name("Birim")
             .DataSource(EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(EStokBirim))
                .Select(i => new { Value = int.Parse(i.Value), Text = i.Text })
            )
            .ValueExpr("Value")
            .DisplayExpr("Text")
            .Placeholder("Stok Birim Seçiniz")
```

It wasn't getting the value before. I think after making this change, the problem was solved.
Destitanion : [Devexpress Support](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t565388/how-to-bind-devextreme-mvc-controls-to-enum)